# When in edit mode, the texture becomes pink/purple on the model (not inverted faces) why is this?

Tags: modeling, uv

I'm working on my model and noticed lately that when I go into edit mode to tweak the vertices or assign new textures, that model's texture changes from light purple to a deep saturated pinkish/purple colour. This doesn't happen when I click on another separate model and go into edit mode, just the face.

I'm making adjustments, so I've cut the model's head in half and applied the mirror  modifier, but I don't think the modifier is causing this effect. All the textures are still in the same folder, they're all assigned properly and in object mode, the texture appears normally. This isn't a lighting issue, it's literally the model's entire head turning this bright saturated pinkish purple colour ONLY when I go into edit mode.

Also due to copyright reasons, I can't show the model, so to help show this problem, I have edited a screenshot of a completely different model as an example of what I'm experiencing.

In edit mode:
[image: **enter image description here**]

In object mode:
[image]

(all the settings and details are the same, I just took screenshots of different models and changed their saturation and edited in effects to help show what I'm seeing)

I'm not sure what is causing this, would anyone have any ideas or advice for how to fix this?

Comment: Usually it means a texture is missing

Comment: @Kiskit But the texture is there and assigned. I wonder if this is a bug?

Comment: Hard to tell from here. Maybe share your blend? At least I can tell you if I observe the same behavior.